# in IE9 or above, border lines are missing

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

---

[image: when the lines are missing.]

as above, the cells in a table don't appear properly.

There isn't any kind of regular phenomenon for this error like only border-top is missing or only border-bottom and left are missing.

[image: when the lines are properly shown.]

The borders should look like this, and when I resize browser window, I get to have the normalized screen.

the funny thing is that it flicks on every resize event. and at some point of resize,

the lines appear and at some other, they disappear over and over again.

I think something overlays the border but this layout consists of table.

each line is separated by a table-row so it's not possible for other elements to overlay.

This only happens in IE9 or above. Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox, Maxthon work just fine.

I googled this issue and found several work-arounds but all of them weren't effective.

I already gave the associated HTML elements 'border-collapse:collapse' and 'border-spacing:0px' attributes.

There's nothing much I can do.

Please help me out

Comment: have you checked that the HTML is valid (http://validator.w3.org/) and that IE9 is showing the page in standards mode?

Comment: Most probably this issue is related to paddings or margins of your divs, try to play with them, maybe some sort of overlapping occur and combined with buggy browser you have the trouble...

Comment: Yes, the validation is okay in html and css //
No, there's no margin or padding values on html elements around the abnormal line area.

Comment: @hina10531    Set up a jsfiddle so others can help diagnose your code. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Terry I'm afraid I can't. It's an auto-generated HTML on SPA handled by Jquery. :[

Comment: What is the exact element that gets the border? `tr` or its `td`s? As far as I know it's better to style `td`s

Comment: @skip405 TR has the border attributes, 'border: 1px solid #ccccc'